# Both Validation and Conversion of RequestParam

Tags: spring, type-conversion

I have several file upload endpoints that take a `MulitpartFile` as the parameter. In all those endpoints I want to do a validation first and respond with my own error message if the file is missing. Also, because I only need the bytes of the files, I want to convert them to byte arrays. So I wrote a Validator for the Mulitpart parameter to check whether it's null:

```
public class NotNullMultipartFileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullMultipartFile, MultipartFile> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final MultipartFile file, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (file == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "My error message");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is working. <strike>I also wrote a Converter, but don't know where to put it because</strike> Spring can do the conversion, but I would have to change the signature of the controller method to take a `byte[]`, and remove the validator:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> upload(@NotNullMultipartFile MultipartFile file) {
    /* do something with the bytes of the file */

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

A custom Converter would take an `@NonNull MultipartFile` parameter and therefore also doesn't allow me to respond with my own error message if the file is missing in a request:

```
public class MultipartFileToBytesConverter implements Converter<MultipartFile, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convert(@NonNull MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            return file.getBytes();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get the two together?

Comment: You don't need the converter, spring already does the conversion.

Comment: You're right. I don't need my own implementation for the converter. But the built-in one also responds with a default error message when the request parameter is missing. How do I change it to my own?

Comment: How about reading the documentation? You can use the `@RequestParam` or `@RequestPart` (probably the last in this case) and set the `required` property to false. Or don't and ditch the validator all together and just write a proper `@ExceptionHandler` in this controller to handle this exception and convert it to what you want.

Comment: It's so simple. Setting `required=false` allows me to respond to when the argument is `null`. Thanks.